# PineScript order entry being inconsistent when a take profit is added

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I'm experiencing a really frustrating behaviour in Pinescript placing orders in the backtest.  It works absolutely fine when a take-profit limit isn't added to the strategy.exit function but becomes inconsistent when it is - for no rational reason I can determine.  In the following code and image, you can see on the image arrows for when a condition is met but you can also see that it isn't always entering a trade.

```
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true, initial_capital=100000, default_qty_type`=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=100)

shortCondition = ema100direction == 'down' and ema100direction[1] == 'up'
longCondition = ema100direction == 'up' and ema100direction[1] == 'down'
            
    
plotshape(series=shortCondition, title="Short Condition", location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, style=shape.triangledown, size=size.tiny)
plotshape(series=longCondition, title="Long Condition", location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, style=shape.triangleup, size=size.tiny)
    
      
var targetPrice = 0.0
var stopPrice = 0.0
    
     
if (longCondition and strategy.position_size <= 0)
    strategy.entry("Long1", strategy.long)
    stopPrice := close * 0.95
    targetPrice = close * (1 + (targetPercent/100))
    strategy.exit("Initial Stop w Limit", from_entry="Long1", stop=stopPrice, limit = targetPrice)


if (shortCondition and strategy.position_size >= 0)
    strategy.entry("Short1", strategy.short)
    stopPrice := close * 1.05
    targetPrice := close * (1 - (targetPercent/100))
    strategy.exit("Initial Stop w Limit", from_entry="Short1", stop=stopPrice, limit = targetPrice)
```

[image]

However, if I remove the limit order from the strategy.exit function, as below, I get the following:

```
shortCondition = ema100direction == 'down' and ema100direction[1] == 'up'
longCondition = ema100direction == 'up' and ema100direction[1] == 'down'
        
plotshape(series=shortCondition, title="Short Condition", location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, style=shape.triangledown, size=size.tiny)
plotshape(series=longCondition, title="Long Condition", location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, style=shape.triangleup, size=size.tiny)
    
var stopPrice = 0.0

if (longCondition and strategy.position_size <= 0)
    strategy.entry("Long1", strategy.long)
    stopPrice := close * 0.95
    strategy.exit("Initial Stop Loss", from_entry="Long1", stop=stopPrice)
    
    
if (shortCondition and strategy.position_size >= 0)
    strategy.entry("Short1", strategy.short)
    stopPrice := close * 1.05
    strategy.exit("Initial Stop Loss", from_entry="Short1", stop=stopPrice)
```

[image]

It's the same whether I have the setting, 'recalculate after order is filled' or 'on every tick' or not.  What am I doing wrong please?

EDIT::
To add to this question:  I plotted both the stopPrice and targetPrice which caused me to wonder whether the issue was being caused where a targetPrice was within the same price range of the bar that was triggering the trade.  I increased the distance of the targetPrice which did have an impact and caught more trades but still not all.  And of those it isn't catching, there is still plenty of clearance between the prices.  Images of the plots below (yellow = target, red = stop) (variables were moved outside of conditional and changed to global 'var').

[image: Example of where it doesnt work]
[image]

UPDATE:
I've tracked the problem down to the default_qty_type as a percent of equity.  If I remove this and leave as the default then it does enter all the trades correctly.  I'm not sure why this should cause an issue as there is no negative equity at any point so I can't see the logic for why it wouldn't enter a trade.  Any pointers much appreciated!

Comment: Something is probably wrong with your `targetPrice`. Try declaring it outside your conditional statement (for now at least) and plot it to see what value it has when your `longCondition` is met.

Comment: Thanks will give that a go, albeit the issue is a lack of entry rather than a price issue related to the exit; and I've already plotted it from within the conditional and it was plotting correctly - so I'm not 100% certain this will prove to be the issue but worth a punt!

Comment: I've edited the question with this added, which shows no clues.  Interestingly I  changing the value of the targetPrice to see what it did and that did have an impact in some but not all cases but for no reason that I can ascertain.

Comment: I've edited the question again as I've discovered the issue relates to using a % of equity rather than a fixed contract for the order size - but uncertain why this is causing an issue.